# CSS: Truncate left text but keep right one following after truncate

Tags: css

I have a case which I'm trying to solve with pure CSS, but I somehow feel like it is not possible (or at least not without using tables).

Imagine following layout

```
<div class="parent">
  <span class="name">
    Some name
  </span>
  <span class="number">
    123
  </span>
</div>
```

I want the `parent` to be of a fixed width and then have `name` followed inline by `number`. However, if the `name` is too long, I would like it to truncate (using ellipsis), but the `number` should remain and be moved to the right until it reaches the border of `parent`.

Here are few examples to illustrate.

```
Short text 1       |
Longer text 12     |
Very, very lon..123|
```

Notice that also the `number` text can have variable length (thus the width can't be fixed).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Flexbox layout does a good job of making this sort of thing a breeze. You can read about the details on using it on [the MDN article "Using CSS Flexible Boxes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), but here is a simple example of how it can solve your layout:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 8em;
}

.name {
    /* Make width shrinkable beyond width of content */
    flex: 0 1 auto;

    /* Make sure text doesn't wrap or push beyond element boundaries */
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

    /* Show an ellipsis when text cuts off */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.number {
    /* Make width inflexible */
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

You can see it in action in [this example JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tamazefehi/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: Suggestion of edit: Please add flex: 0 1 auto to .name and flex: 0 0 auto to .number to be more flex-box standard.

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly like I wanted it. I guess I should finally look into the felx-box feature. However, pity it's only supported on the most modern browsers.